# Sodamide vs alcoholic KOH

Tags: organic-chemistry

My textbook says

> In the presence of strong base such as KOH and at high temperatures, triple bond at terminal C-atom of higher alkynes migrates to give disubstituted alkyne.Therefore alcoholic KOH is used when rearrangement is not a problem,on the other hand terminal alkynes can be produced using NaNH2 in liquid ammonia as those alkynes essentially donot
> rearrange.

Why is that so?I know KOH is not as strong a base as sodamide but why alkynes formed by using it are capable of rearrangement while those formed through sodamide are not?
The product is same in both cases,what its got to do with the reagent?And what is the significance of high temperature?

Comment: I guess the last sentence in your book should read "as *in* those, alkynes *do* essentially not rearrange".

Comment: Oh,that makes sense.But  how does the reagant effect it?

Comment: Well, what is the mechanism of this rearrangement? (Btw. please give the name of the textbook, and what is the audience?)

Comment: That book is indeed bad, from the short look I had. Stuffed to the brim with facts, little in the way of adequate didactics, and a lot of bad grammar to mislead the student. I honestly don't know a good alternative, my highschool chemistry books were in German, and first semester university books would not span the whole field, you'd have to buy two or three. You might try Atkins "General Chemistry". It's regarded as OK to help not too ambitions biology or medicine students over their chemistry, and Atkins is a fine writer.

Comment: Anyway, a really strong base like NaNH2 deprotonates the terminal alkyne, and that's that. Actually amides tend to shift triple bonds to the end of an alkyl chain. That's called the "alkyne zipper". I'm not sure how the reaction with KOH should proceed towards a disubstituted alkyne. Subsequent addition/elimination steps in the heat?

Comment: I have come up with this possible reasoning(not sure if it's correct) Reaction of alcoholic KOH with vicinal dihallide takes place at high temperatures(100~200°C) due to the fact that KOH is less strong a base and doing second elimination would require added heat,this heat in turn favours rearrangement of the bond.On the other hand reaction of sodamide happens at -33°C (it's a strong base so second elimination will occur at low temp)Without the heat the rearrangement will not occur.(relation of heat and rearrangement is not clear to me )

Comment: That's about what would happen, yes. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/09%3A_Alkynes_-_An_Introduction_to_Organic_Synthesis/9.03%3A_Preparation_of_Alkynes_-_Elimination_Reactions_of_Dihalides , scroll down to "Terminal Alyknes"  With NaNH2, the reaction is locked as R-CC-Na, with NaOH not, and if you heat the latter, it will rearrange into the more stable disubstituted alkyne.